# Why does white font appear visible when I export excel screenshot to vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I used the following code to export excel screenshot to powerpoint

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()
'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Range Into a New PowerPoint Presentation
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = Worksheets("Overall").Range("B2:AH47")

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    'Set position:
      myShape.Left = 35
      myShape.Top = 15

    'setting size
      myShape.Height = 510


'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

and it throws a screenshot to ppt which looks like this :

[image]

All the red square boxes show text which was in white colour. They are hidden when viewed in excel but they appear only when the selection is screen captured and exported to ppt

Please help!

Comment: Hey Dirk, none of them work.

Comment: I dont mind as long as that picture gets sent to ppt. What should I need to change for bitmap

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to rendering text in metafiles on a transparent background. There are two ways you can resolve this:

- Copy the Excel range as a bitmap using `rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap`. As the bitmap format does not support transparency, the cell background is automatically rendered in white. The disadvantage of this option is that the copied range no longer scales well as it is no longer in a vector format.
- Explicitly remove the transparency from the cells by setting the cell to be filled with a white background. Then copy the range using `rng.CopyPicture xlPrinter, XlPicture`. When using this option you can still use a scalable metafile in PowerPoint.

Comment: When i use `rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap` , I get an error in the following line of the code `mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2` and the error is `Shapes.PasteSpecial : Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable`

Comment: @Vinaybilla: It's obviously not going to work because the clipboard now contains only bitmap format and you are trying to paste an enhanced metafile which is just not present. If the clipboard only contains a bitmap you need to use `Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap` instead (or just use the regular `Shapes.Paste` method)